# Same processor with different names

Tags: microprocessor

Following types/variants/package of P1022 freescale processors are available in market:

1)P1022NXE2LFB

2)P1022NXN2LFB

3)P1022NXE2HFB

4)P1022NXN2EFB

5)P1022NXN2HFB

6)P1022NSE2EFB

7)P1022NSN2EFB

8)P1022NSE2HFB

9)P1022NSN2HFB

10)P1022NSE2LFB

11)P1022NSN2LFB

12)P1022NXE2EFB

However, datasheet of most of the packages is same, my question is how above packages differ from each other and how name signifies that difference.

Comment: This must all be in a datasheet somewhere. Read between the lines (i.e. carefully), manufacturers do not arbitrarily make up new part numbers unless there are actual part differences.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Freescale's comparison page](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=P1022&tab=Buy_Parametric_Tab&pspll=1&fromSearch=false&uc=true&lang_cd=en).  I believe all of the models you listed are in the table.  They vary by cpu/bus clock speeds and min/max operating temperatures.

Comment: Hey thanks, can you explain the nomenclature of packages as well ?